# How to iterate through UV faces via Python code

Tags: python, uv, uv-image-editor

I have a model and I have unwrapped its faces using simple cubic unwrap. I would like to iterate through the unwrapped faces and select and apply a few operations from external addons to each of them. But I don't quite see in the examples from the documentation how can I make such iteration. How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49341/how-to-get-the-uv-corresponding-to-a-vertex-via-the-python-api   Recent one re selecting    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212287/select-everything-inside-the-uv-0-1 answers show both a bmesh and a mesh way.  another https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170318/how-to-get-data-and-edit-it-on-uv-map-edges another recent one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213318/how-to-rotate-uv-and-preserve-the-correct-aspect-ratio

Comment: There is also an example in _`text editor > templates > python > Operator Mesh UV`_

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out I think I might have been looking at the wrong examples this whole time.